# How do I prevent end messages from closing Nodejs streams?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

In a Node server I have a series of streams piped together.  Say, for example:

```
streamA.pipe(streamB).pipe(streamC)
```

Eventually streamA completes and at that point I want to switch the downstreams to another source:

```
streamD.pipe(streamB).pipe(streamC)
```

But when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
Error: write after end
```

How can I prevent streamA from closing my downstreams?  Or how can I open my downstreams back up to switch them over to streamD?

Also, my use case requires that I wait until streamA end.  I can't switch the streams prematurely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Been googling the same thing, you can just add

`streamA.pipe(streamB, {end: false}).pipe(streamC, {end: false})`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found that if I `unpipe()` my downstream when I receive the 'end' event then the upstream won't have a chance to close my downstream and everything is Ok.

```
streamA.on('end', function() {
    downstreams.forEach(downstream => {
        streamA.unpipe(downstream);
    });
}
```

If there is a more canonical solution then please feel free to post it.

Comment: omg you saved my day, thank you so much. I love streams now ahah.